# Where can I find a screening tool similar to what is used by the Google Stock Screener?

Tags: javascript

I'm looking to create or find a screener tool similar to [this](http://www.google.com/finance/stockscreener) that will read through the records in a database, allow you to select the criteria, create a histogram of said records and criteria, and allow the user to sort and filter through the data, just like the Google Stock Screener.

How would I go about creating something like this or is there somewhere that I could find a plug-in that would allow this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think [Flot](http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/time.html) would be a good javascript library to try for this. I've used it to display share market data in the past and it deals with time series data fairly well. It's not very hard to add interactive elements.